# Nginx with Ubuntu and Rails on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to get nginx to work with a rails app, but nginx wont start after installation and changing its config file.

Here is the output its giving me:

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build the types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

And here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
# This is example contains the bare mininum to get nginx going with
# Unicorn or Rainbows! servers.  Generally these configuration settings
# are applicable to other HTTP application servers (and not just Ruby
# ones), so if you have one working well for proxying another app
# server, feel free to continue using it.
#
# The only setting we feel strongly about is the fail_timeout=0
# directive in the "upstream" block.  max_fails=0 also has the same
# effect as fail_timeout=0 for current versions of nginx and may be
# used in its place.
#
# Users are strongly encouraged to refer to nginx documentation for more
# details and search for other example configs.

# you generally only need one nginx worker unless you're serving
# large amounts of static files which require blocking disk reads
worker_processes 1;

# # drop privileges, root is needed on most systems for binding to port 80
# # (or anything < 1024).  Capability-based security may be available for
# # your system and worth checking out so you won't need to be root to
# # start nginx to bind on 80
user nobody nogroup; # for systems with a "nogroup"
# user nobody nobody; # for systems with "nobody" as a group instead

# Feel free to change all paths to suite your needs here, of course
pid /path/to/nginx.pid;
error_log /path/to/nginx.error.log;


events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  # nginx will find this file in the config directory set at nginx build time
  include mime.types;

  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # click tracking!
  access_log /path/to/nginx.access.log combined;

  # you generally want to serve static files with nginx since neither
  # Unicorn nor Rainbows! is optimized for it at the moment
  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff

  # we haven't checked to see if Rack::Deflate on the app server is
  # faster or not than doing compression via nginx.  It's easier
  # to configure it all in one place here for static files and also
  # to disable gzip for clients who don't get gzip/deflate right.
  # There are other gzip settings that may be needed used to deal with
  # bad clients out there, see http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipModule
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;

  # this can be any application server, not just Unicorn/Rainbows!
  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
    # single worker for timing out).

    # for UNIX domain socket setups:
    server unix:/home/portfolio/tmp/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for TCP setups, point these to your backend servers
    # server 192.168.0.7:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.8:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.9:8080 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    # enable one of the following if you're on Linux or FreeBSD
     listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
    # listen 80 default accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD

    # If you have IPv6, you'll likely want to have two separate listeners.
    # One on IPv4 only (the default), and another on IPv6 only instead
    # of a single dual-stack listener.  A dual-stack listener will make
    # for ugly IPv4 addresses in $remote_addr (e.g ":ffff:10.0.0.1"
    # instead of just "10.0.0.1") and potentially trigger bugs in
    # some software.
    # listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on; # deferred or accept_filter recommended

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    # ~2 seconds is often enough for most folks to parse HTML/CSS and
    # retrieve needed images/icons/frames, connections are cheap in
    # nginx so increasing this is generally safe...
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /var/www/portfolio/public;

    # Prefer to serve static files directly from nginx to avoid unnecessary
    # data copies from the application server.
    #
    # try_files directive appeared in in nginx 0.7.27 and has stabilized
    # over time.  Older versions of nginx (e.g. 0.6.x) requires
    # "if (!-f $request_filename)" which was less efficient:
    # http://bogomips.org/unicorn.git/tree/examples/nginx.conf?id=v3.3.1#n127
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
      # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
      #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # enable this if you forward HTTPS traffic to unicorn,
      # this helps Rack set the proper URL scheme for doing redirects:
      # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
      # can be set properly within the Rack application
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;

      # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
      # Comet/long-poll/streaming.  It's also safe to set if you're using
      # only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx, but not slow
      # clients.  You normally want nginx to buffer responses to slow
      # clients, even with Rails 3.1 streaming because otherwise a slow
      # client can become a bottleneck of Unicorn.
      #
      # The Rack application may also set "X-Accel-Buffering (yes|no)"
      # in the response headers do disable/enable buffering on a
      # per-response basis.
      # proxy_buffering off;

      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # Rails error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /var/www/portfolio/public;
    }
  }
}

types_hash_max_size: 2048;
types_hash_bucket_size: 64;
```

Comment: This would imply you need to change `server_names_hash_bucket_size`?   http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2008/11/14/fix-nginx-increase-server_names_hash_bucket_size

Comment: @toxaq I added server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; to the http section but I still get the same error?

Comment: More info here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization Are you restarting or testing the config each time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I made another droplet with digital ocean with nginx already installed and just looked at the nginx.conf file and they had this in there http section

```
types_hash_max_size 2048;
```

Comment: thanks for adding this.  i'm using do but installing nginx manually.